# Registering a Blazor server Pwa as file handler

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor-server-side

I am trying to have my Blazor server Pwa handle txt files from Windows file system, following the steps from "Registering your app as a file editor via File Handling" at https://www.thinktecture.com/en/net/adding-superpowers-to-your-blazor-webassembly-app-with-project-fugu-apis/

I can right-click a txt file on Windows Explorer and select my Pwa to open it.
It successfully opens the Pwa on the right page but it throws the exception "**Deserialization of interface types is not supported**."

Manifest file handlers as follows:

```
  "file_handlers": [
    {
      "action": "/test",
      "accept": {
        "text/*": [ ".txt" ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

My action page:

```
@page "/test"
@using KristofferStrube.Blazor.FileSystem;
@using Thinktecture.Blazor.FileHandling
@inject FileHandlingService _fileHandlingService


@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await _fileHandlingService.SetConsumerAsync(async (launchParams) =>
            {
                foreach (var fileSystemHandle in launchParams.Files)
                {
                    if (fileSystemHandle is FileSystemFileHandle fileSystemFileHandle)
                    {
                        var file = await fileSystemFileHandle.GetFileAsync();
                        var text = await file.TextAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Steps to reproduce the issue:

Create a new Blazor server project and name it TestFileHandling
install nuget Thinktecture.Blazor.FileHandling

On Program.cs, register the service before builder.build:

```
builder.Services.AddFileHandlingService();
```

Copy next files from https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.Blazor/tree/main/samples/Thinktecture.Blazor.Sample/wwwroot to your wwwroot folder:
service-worker.js and service-worker.published.js

Add an icon 512x512px to wwwroot folder. Name it icon-512.png
You may create one from https://placeholderimage.dev/

Add a manifest.json file to wwwroot folder with the next content:

```
{
  "name": "TestFileHandling",
  "short_name": "Test",
  "start_url": "./",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#03173d",
  "prefer_related_applications": false,
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "file_handlers": [{
    "action": "./test",
    "accept": {
      "text/plain": [".txt"]
    }
  }]
}
```

On _Host.cshtml, inside head, insert:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

On _Host.cshtml, below blazor server.js, insert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
</script>
```

Create a TestPage.razor inside your Pages folder with the next content:

```
@page "/test"
@using KristofferStrube.Blazor.FileSystem;
@using Thinktecture.Blazor.FileHandling
@inject FileHandlingService _fileHandlingService

<p>Launch Queue is supported? @(_isFileHandlingSupported ? "yes" : "no")</p>

<p>Open a TXT file by right-clicking it in Explorer/Finder and choosing this demo application.</p>

<textarea @bind="_text" readonly></textarea>

@code {
    private bool _isFileHandlingSupported;
    private string _text = "";

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _isFileHandlingSupported = await _fileHandlingService.IsSupportedAsync();
            if (_isFileHandlingSupported)
            {
                await _fileHandlingService.SetConsumerAsync(async (p) =>
                {
                    foreach (var fileSystemHandle in p.Files)
                    {
                        if (fileSystemHandle is FileSystemFileHandle fileSystemFileHandle)
                        {
                            var file = await fileSystemFileHandle.GetFileAsync();
                            var text = await file.TextAsync();
                            _text = text;
                            StateHasChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
```

Comment: Does the Thinktecture.Blazor.Sample https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.Blazor.git worked on your machine? Which browser do you use?

Comment: The sample works Ok, so I copied the code from FileHandling.razor.cs into my test page.
But it throws InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.
So I moved the code to the OnAfterRenderAsync override.
Then I get System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSInProcessObjectReference'.  
My browser is Chrome 115.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error :-/ I basically copied your action page code into FileHandling.razor of the sample application and commented the file handling code in FileHandling.razor.cs. That worked, the uploaded file content was written into the console.

Comment: @Stef Chaser, thanks for your time. I have edited the question to display the steps to reproduce the error

Comment: The difference I see from Thinktecture.Blazor.Sample is it is a WebAssembly project, not a Blazor-server one. Might it be that file handling feature is not available on Blazor server?